# CKan how to fetch resource as XML/JSON

Tags: json, xml, resources, ckan

If suppose you have inserted data into datastore using CKan API:

```
curl -X POST http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/datastore_create -H "Authorization: <Api-key>" -d @mycompanydata.json
```

With help of the action API, I could fetch data as follows:

```
http://demo.ckan.org/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=<my-resouce-id>&filters={“hid”:”23455-XJ31”}
```

Can i fetch the same resource as XML? How?

Answer (score 0):

No, CKAN's Datastore returns data as JSON only.

e.g.
http://demo.ckan.org/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=0c2bd47a-6ac5-412e-a337-1b45a952e07e&limit=5

Comment: Ok. If I need to expose my data stored in CKan datastore as XML and JSON with full working REST API support on it then is CKan a platform for this? How? With extension plugins on it? Or I need to write my own REST API to fetch data?